# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ALAssetsLibrary", referenced from: GooglePlus(NSData+GPPAdditions.o)

Tags: objective-c, linker-errors, armv7

This is the error I am getting after adding `-ObjC` in "Other Linker Flags":

> "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ALAssetsLibrary", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in GooglePlus(NSData+GPPAdditions.o)
>         objc-class-ref in GooglePlus(UIDevice+GPPAdditions.o)   "_kABPersonFirstNameProperty", referenced from:
>         ___48+[GPPAddressBook loadDeviceContactsWithHandler:]_block_invoke in
>   GooglePlus(GPPAddressBook.o)   "_ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople",
>   referenced from:
>         ___48+[GPPAddressBook loadDeviceContactsWithHandler:]_block_invoke in
>   GooglePlus(GPPAddressBook.o)   "_ABMultiValueGetCount", referenced
>   from:
>         ___48+[GPPAddressBook loadDeviceContactsWithHandler:]_block_invoke in
>   GooglePlus(GPPAddressBook.o)   "_ABRecordCopyValue", referenced from:
>         ___48+[GPPAddressBook loadDeviceContactsWithHandler:]_block_invoke in
>   GooglePlus(GPPAddressBook.o)   "_ABPersonHasImageData", referenced
>   from:
>         ___48+[GPPAddressBook loadDeviceContactsWithHandler:]_block_invoke in
>   GooglePlus(GPPAddressBook.o)   "_ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat",
>   referenced from:
>         ___48+[GPPAddressBook loadDeviceContactsWithHandler:]_block_invoke in
>   GooglePlus(GPPAddressBook.o)   "_kABPersonEmailProperty", referenced
>   from:
>         ___48+[GPPAddressBook loadDeviceContactsWithHandler:]_block_invoke in
>   GooglePlus(GPPAddressBook.o)   "_ABAddressBookGetPersonCount",
>   referenced from:
>         ___48+[GPPAddressBook loadDeviceContactsWithHandler:]_block_invoke in
>   GooglePlus(GPPAddressBook.o)   "_ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions",
>   referenced from:
>         +[GPPAddressBook loadDeviceContactsWithHandler:] in GooglePlus(GPPAddressBook.o)   "_MPMoviePlayerThumbnailImageKey",
>   referenced from:
>         -[GPPMediaPreviewView thumbnailImageRequestDidFinish:] in GooglePlus(GPPMediaPreviewView.o)   "_ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex",
>   referenced from:
>         ___48+[GPPAddressBook loadDeviceContactsWithHandler:]_block_invoke in
>   GooglePlus(GPPAddressBook.o)
>   "_MPMoviePlayerThumbnailImageRequestDidFinishNotification", referenced
>   from:
>         -[GPPMediaPreviewView initWithFrame:mediaAttachment:] in GooglePlus(GPPMediaPreviewView.o)
>         -[GPPMediaPreviewView thumbnailImageRequestDidFinish:] in GooglePlus(GPPMediaPreviewView.o)
>   "_ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion", referenced from:
>         +[GPPAddressBook loadDeviceContactsWithHandler:] in GooglePlus(GPPAddressBook.o)   "_kABPersonLastNameProperty",
>   referenced from:
>         ___48+[GPPAddressBook loadDeviceContactsWithHandler:]_block_invoke in
>   GooglePlus(GPPAddressBook.o)
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MPMoviePlayerController", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in GooglePlus(GPPMediaPreviewView.o) ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I have  already added those frameworks (AVFoundation, QuartzCore, CoreMotion,  SystemConfiguration, Security, Social, CoreLocation, GLKit, MapKit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those kind of error you have add the following frameworks:

Assets Library
AddressBook
coremedia
Accounts
Media player

Answer (score 3):

You have to add the following frameworks:

- CoreMotion.framework
- CoreMedia.framework
- Accounts.framework
- AssetsLibrary.framework
- AddressBook.framework
- MediaPlayer.framework

Hope it helps.